# React Confrim Alert Plugin Over Modal

Tags: reactjs

is there any way to let react confirm alert display over modal? (on top of modal)

I'm using instruction [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-confirm-alert) and follow exactly the description.

Below is the code example from the link:

```
    import { confirmAlert } from 'react-confirm-alert'; 
    import 'react-confirm-alert/src/react-confirm-alert.css';
    submit = () => {
    confirmAlert({
      title: 'Confirm to submit',
      message: 'Are you sure to do this.',
      buttons: [
        {
          label: 'Yes',
          onClick: () => alert('Click Yes')
        },
        {
          label: 'No',
          onClick: () => alert('Click No')
        }
      ],
       closeOnEscape: true,  //**only press on ESC on keyboard to close**
       closeOnClickOutside: false  //**prevent click over white space to close the alert messag**e
    });
  };
```